# ioS 7: How to populate a toolbar with custom icons?

Tags: ios, iphone

For iOS7, leveraging storyboard, how do I populate a toolbar with custom image icons?

An example, would be Instagrams bottom nav bar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **storyboard**, you could set "image" property of **UIBarButtonItem**.
In case of **code**, use any method starting with **initWithImage**.